# Ubuntu 18.04 5.1 front speakers not working

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, system-settings, speakers

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new machine and plugged my 5.1 surround sound speakers into it and have changed the audio profile:
[image: Sound Settings]

However when I test my speakers all but the front left and right are producing sound and I am not sure what I should look into in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system tries to play in 3.1 surround mode.

Try to install PulseAudio control panel:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

It gives you more options. Maybe there is an option to choose 5.1 surround.

Comment: [EDIT] ...Yes. When you start Pulse Audio in the 'configuration' tab. Just chose a 5.1 profile.